# a command substitute

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting, symlink

I'm not going to lie. This is for an assignment. I'm stuck and its kind a frustrating so i came here as my last resort so please help me out.

So, I need to make a script to find and print, that if the path is a relative or absolute path. I'm stuck in the last part where the prof want's me to do a command line substitute,which I have no idea how to do. This is what I have so far.

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "$0: please insert one valid file name;found $# ($*) "
    echo 1>&2 "Usage: $0 [Filename..]"
    exit 2
fi

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
        echo 1>&2 "$0: file name cannot be empty; found $# ($*) "
        echo 1>&2 "Usage: $0 [filename...] "
        exit 2
fi

if [ ! -L "$1" ] ; then
        echo 1>&2 "$0: The pathname '$1' is not a symlink"
        echo 1>&2 "Usage: '$0' [symlink] "
        exit 2
fi

a=ls "$1" | awk '{ print $NF }'

if [ -z "$a" ] ; then
        echo 1>&2 "$0: Pathname is empty "
        exit 3
fi


    type=$(a)
    case "$b" in
    /* )    type='an Absolute Pathname' ;;
    * )     type='a Relative Pathname in the current directory' ;;  # the "default" match
    echo "pathname'$a' is $type"

    esac
```

**This is screen shot of what he want us to do.**
[image]

please ask any questions if the question isn't clear enough.
Thank you

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text if possible.

Comment: As your professor what to do if there are files called e.g. `A -> B` in the directory.  Pro tip: Use `readlink` instead of parsing `ls -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is far from ready, but you're on the right track now.

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 1>&2 "$0: please insert one valid file name;found $# ($*) "
    echo 1>&2 "Usage: $0 [Filename..]"
    exit 2
fi

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
        echo 1>&2 "$0: file name cannot be empty; found $# ($*) "
        echo 1>&2 "Usage: $0 [filename...] "
        exit 2
fi

if [ ! -L "$1" ] ; then
        echo 1>&2 "$0: The pathname '$1' is not a symlink"
        echo 1>&2 "Usage: '$0' [symlink] "
        exit 2
fi

a=$(ls -l "$1" | awk '{ print $NF }')

if [ -z "$a" ] ; then
        echo 1>&2 "$0: A Really Good Error Message."
        exit 3
fi

#    type=$a
    case "$a" in
    /*)    type='an Absolute Pathname' ;;
    *)     type='a Relative Pathname in the current directory' ;;  # the "default" match
    esac
    echo "pathname'$a' is $type"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but do i have to remove the that if statement in order for this to work? I'm completely lost, I don't understand what he's asking us to do. could you please check out the new picture that I updated right now.

Comment: Well, no. As explained in the instruction this is to make sure the listing (the `ls` command) worked. And to exit if it failed. But I have no idea of what a good error message might be here. I can't think of any situation in which it would be applicable to print "Pathname is empty". If the link is dead, it would show the target anyhow.

Comment: nvm its working now. thank you so much. error was in the symbolink link part and u fixed it :)

Comment: Don't forget your last line. `echo "$type symlink: '$1' -> '$a'"`

Comment: @tomas ther is no need for an extra variable `a`. Also it's bad to store `ls` output in scripts. `ls` produces human readable output thus not suited in scripts. Either  `a="$1"` or  `case "$1" in` ..

Comment: yeah I fixed those. everything is good now. Thank you